# Are there any disadvantages to dispelling demons as they spawn from Fade Rifts?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

When a new wave of demons is in the process of spawning from an active Fade Rift, certain abilities like the Mage's Dispel, or the Templar Warrior specialisation's Spell Purge will insta-gib any demons they hit if they land before the demon spawns. Clearly this has the advantage of making the wave easier to deal with as you get fewer enemies spawning (or none at all in some cases). However, does doing this also have any disadvantages associated with it? For instance, do I get less XP? Less loot? Can I miss out on any Codex entries?

Alternatively, are they any reasons why I might *not* want to gib demons in this way and to just let them spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the enemies that are spawned from Fade Rifts don't drop regular loot, but they do all drop research items. Dispelling enemies before they're active means you won't get those at all. The research items are used to unlock Codex information, and even a damage bonus against researched enemies, so using Dispel throughout the game, especially to prevent the bigger enemies' appearing, can leave you a bit weaker against rifts by the end.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're dispel heavy and you rarely have to fight more than a few demons from every rift, does having fewer demon-specific bonuses really matter all that much?

Comment: @JonK Demons show up in missions without their being rifts around. Especially in some of the main quest missions. Depending on difficulty, missing out on that bonus can certainly hurt in a few spots, yes.

Comment: Ha, I'm not masochistic enough to play on Nightmare so I couldn't really comment on what it's like on the harder difficulties. I found a lot of the fights that I *really* wasn't interested in, double Pride demons and such, were often avoidable to some extent. In truth though I mostly just dispel Wraiths and Shades, there's plenty of those as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The only downside to dispelling demons is that it generates less Focus than if you fought normally and, optimally, performed some cross-class combos on them.

Comment: Good point about the focus, although I rarely actually use the focus abilities so I have little need to farm it from anywhere. That said, if I really wanted to farm focus from a rift, I'd just keep resetting it after killing the first wave by running away from it...